# How do I find a matching plug & header pair?

Tags: connector, component-selection

I'm browsing [board to wire type connectors](http://bit.ly/1bNjc8p). My aim is to solder a header on my PCB, and use a plug to receive/transmit signals from it.

As far as I see, the headers and plugs are sold separately, and there is not explicit information which headers are pair to which plugs. When I choose a header from the list, how do I choose a correct plug for it? How do I correctly find matching plug and header pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Choose plug and header from the same product range, and check the manufacture's datasheets.

Comment: The data sheet is key here ... some headers may fit multiple connectors and the other way round ... for instance you can have right angle connectors or headers as well as straight ones.. it depends on how you want the wire to come away from the board...

Comment: Here is an example of a Web page and Data sheet, the contact , the housing and the header all have specific part numbers for the manufacturer. The distributor will also have their own part numbers just to make it interesting. http://www.jst.com/home23.html , http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eXH.pdf

Comment: The Digikey.com web site is actually quite nice for this. If you look up a connector, for example http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0022272081/WM4117-ND/1130583 (chosen at random) and scroll down the page, you will find a list of mating connectors. Note: not all of these pages list the mating product(s) but most do.